# DOM event-listeners garbage collection

Tags: dom, garbage-collection, event-listener

If an event listener is attached to every cell in a particular column of a table, and then every row is removed from the table, to avoid memory leaks is it necessary for the developer to remove the event-listeners before the rows are deleted, or do the browsers clean things up?

Edit: the article that Michael suggested says `event delegation` performs better than binding the listener directly to every cell in the table, but I am not sure if it is better from a garbage-collection perspective or just performs better. Please comment.  From the article:

```
        $('table').on('click', 'td', function () {

            $(this).toggleClass('active');

        });
```

is said to be superior to:

```
        $('table td').on('click', function () {

            $(this).toggleClass('active');

        });
```

Edit2: and the [jQuery documentation of .on() and event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) also focuses on performance, but the question of what happens from a garbage-collection perspective when rows are repeatedly deleted *en masse* from a large table, and the cell-click is being listened to by the delegated mechanism, remains.

Comment: have a look on this 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Memory_Management  

it might be helpful

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am not sure, but i guess this brilliant article will clean things up (search for "Garbage Collection"): http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/

Comment: Downvoted because the answer does not contain any actual information, merely points to a resource (which may become stale at some point in the future, completely invalidating the "answer"). One way to rectify this -- keeping the link to the otherwise good article -- is to duplicate or synthesize the argument in the article as bullet points in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly but i think browser(JavaScript engine) is responsible for Garbage-Collection.

and as i know this mechanism is automatic in new generation browsers

so, flow will be like this,

```
1. you create cells
2. you attach listeners
3. memory allocated
4. you remove cells
5. listeners becomes dangling
6. Garbage collector clears it
7. you are happy
```

also there are some mechanism provide to clear it explicitly, search SO for that and there will be many questions related to that

But again i am not sure ! so wait for experts to come up with solid answer

Comment: thanks for the first mozilla link and this overview; I've edited my original question to highlight specifically the question where potentially thousands and thousands of cells would have a listener listening for their click event; my table is periodically (say every 30 seconds) refreshed with real-time data via an ajax XHR, resulting in the deletion of all previous rows.